# jQuery .on() not working with jquery-ujs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have a rails app that renders views via jquery-ujs. (data-remote in the URLs, then a load of js.erb files with things like:

```
$('#whatever').html('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

In my main JS file, I have event handlers like so:

```
$('.action').on('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

but the on() behaviour does not attach to the new elements inserted by jquery-ujs. I can go into the console and paste the above code and everything attaches fine (once the elements are already there), but straight after ujs fires, no luck. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

This is with jQuery 1.9.1 and Rails 3.2.13 btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind `on` to a parent like `document`. Now, you're binding directly to the `.action` element, which is essentially the same as using `$('.action').click()`. Because you're adding elements to the DOM later, you need to delegate the handler to something that's already present before the elements are inserted. You can provide a selector as the second parameter of the `.on` event to bind it to `.action`.

Have a look at the 'Direct and delegated events' section [in jQuery's API documentation for `.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.action', function () {
    console.log('Clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Aha! That's the one! Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since `#whatever` seems to be static (*exists all the time*) you can delegate the handling to it..

```
$('#whatever').on('click','.action', function(e){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

(*assuming that the `.action` elements are added inside the `#whatever` element*)

---

See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events for more on delegated events